# Working of selections

Tags: probability

There are eight finalists in the 400 m athletics at
the world championships. Three of the finalists
are from the USA, and the others are from five
different countries. The rules for allocating a
lane to each of the runners state that runners
from the same country cannot be placed in
adjacent lanes and also that the two outside
lanes cannot be used by runners from the same
country. How many different ways are there of
allocating the eight lanes for this race?

Comment: When they say "two outside lanes", are they referring to the inside and outside lanes?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1) First place the runners not from the USA in order.

2) Next pick 3 of the resulting gaps for the US runners, and then subtract
   the possibilities where 2 of the gaps chosen are on the outside.

3) Assign the US runners to their gaps.

---

Here's another approach:

1) Count the number of ways to line up all the runners in order.

2) Subtract the ways in which all 3 US runners are in adjacent lanes.

3) Subtract the ways exactly 2 US runners are in adjacent lanes.

4) Subtract the ways in which the outside lanes have US runners, but
no 2 US runners are adjacent.

Comment: I dont understand how to do it your way? Like do i make 11 gaps and place the non USA runners leaving a gap in between each one?

Comment: After you place the 5 non-US runners in order, you have 6 gaps remaining in which the US runners must go (since they are not next to each other).  Now you have to pick 3 of these, but subtract off the choices where both outside gaps are chosen.